# What's with the occasional hidden ad?

Tags: bug, advertising

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot there is an ad-services add in the corner of the screen. While I recognize that I have a dark extension (which is why I saw it), the ad is still present in the regular styled website too, just hidden better. If we're going to have ads rendered, shouldn't it be visible to the user? Hiding it seems like it's 1.) (possibly) Violating the contract with the ad provider and 2.) Not being upfront about what's being loaded into the dom.

Comment: not my field of expertise, but it looks like a google ad

Comment: Potentially worth asking on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ since it is more likely a Stack Exchange issue rather than a Worldbuilding specific one.

Comment: Huh!  SE has been testing ads on the network (Workplace gets a ton of them), but I hadn't yet seen any here.  The ads I've seen elsewhere have been largely irrelevant and often animated, so these are not like the community-promotion ads we're used to.

Comment: Whereas I use a decent ad-and-tracking blocker, so the worst I get is a big white space where the parent div didn't get squashed (haven't seen that on WB, or anywhere on the SE network).